# Letter 'c' stopped working in MS Word on mac

Tags: ms-office, word-processor

So in MS Word on Mac it simply does not show letter 'c'. Here it works fine, in browser letter 'c' works super fine, in the mail - everywhere but in MS Word (version 16.54 (21101001) mac monterey 12.01

**Update:**
this is only in one single document (shared via OneDrive and accessed simulataneusly by co-author)

Comment: What Mac - is this with an external keyboard, or a laptop? I presume you've restarted? Check autocorrect isn't replacing it.

Comment: its both external (bluetooth) keyboard and the regular one. And it is only in MS Word.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the typeface ("font") of the offending text.  If that fixes it, arguably the typeface is corrupt.